# react-native run-android deploys old build

Tags: react-native

I'm building a react-native android app.  I am using Windows as my development area.  To push my app to my phone, I simply connect the phone via USB to my computer and then I run the command `react-native run-android`.

This works fine and exactly as expected on one of my android phones.

I have a second older android phone, but every time I run `react-native run-android`, it receives an old and out-dated version of the app from 2-3 days ago, when I last connected the phone to my computer.  I tried to manually uninstall the app from my phone, I tried restarting my phone, I tried taking out the battery, but every time I deploy, it still receives the old version.

How do I get my second android phone to receive the latest version?

Comment: what version of android is the older android phone running on?

Comment: @quidproquo it is android 4.4.2, HTC Sense 6.0 -- it is my HTC Desire 510 phone

Answer (score 2):

If you look at their [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#connecting-to-the-development-server), `Reload JS` only works on Android 5 and above with USB debugging. You may want to try method 2 for older devices:

> Method 2: Connect via Wi-Fi
>
> You can also connect to the development server over Wi-Fi. You'll first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable, but once that has been done you can debug wirelessly by following these instructions. You'll need your development machine's current IP address before proceeding.
>
> Open a terminal and type /sbin/ifconfig to find your machine's IP address.
>
> Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
>   Open your React Native app on your device.
>   You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.
>   Open the in-app Developer menu.
>   Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device.
>   Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
>   Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.
>
> You can now enable Live reloading from the Developer menu. Your app will reload whenever your JavaScript code has changed.

Comment: instead of this, do you know also if there's an apk file in my development machine that I can just email over to my phone?

Comment: yeah I think you can build a debug build with the JS bundled in so you don't need a development server. I'll see if I can find the documentation for that